# Retrieving data from plist array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist, nsdata

I am having major difficulty getting my head around this one.

I'm creating a quiz. Within the plist there are questions...and possible answers, here is my plist

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>quest</key>
<array/>
<key>Quest1</key>
<string>3234</string>
<key>A</key>
<string>3</string>
<key>B</key>
<string>2</string>
<key>C</key>
<string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The array is called `quest` and I want to be able to pull out "Quest1" from the code and the 3 answers.... here is my code but I seem to be missing something to get it to display

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistpath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"question.plist"];
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistpath])
{
    plistpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"];
}
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistpath];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization     propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (!temp)
{
NSLog(@"error reading plist: %@, format:%d",errorDesc, format);

}
  self.question.text = [temp objectForKey:@"quest"];
  self.answer1.text =[temp objectForKey:@"A"];
  self.answer2.text =[temp objectForKey:@"B"];
  self.answer3.text =[temp objectForKey:@"C"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..it will help you

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistpath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"question.plist"];
NSMutableArray *savedStock = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];
 for (int i=0; i<[savedStock count]; i++)
    {
        [A-array addObject:[[savedStock objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"A"]];
        [B-array addObject:[[savedStock objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"B"]];
    }
```